# 'A4J' is undefined

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, myfaces

i have a problem with ajax4jsf library on ie7 it give me error 'A4J is undefined' but this error not appear on firefox and chrome

library which i used
myfaces1.1.5 and ajax4jsf1.1

Here is my `web.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.4" xmlns="java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"; xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"; xsi:schemaLocation="java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee java.sun.com/xml/ns/…;
<context-param>
<param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
<param-value>server</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
<param-name>org.apache.myfaces.NUMBER_OF_VIEWS_IN_SESSION</param-name>
<param-value>20</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
<param-name>org.apache.myfaces.SERIALIZE_STATE_IN_SESSION</param-name>
<param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
<param-name>org.apache.myfaces.COMPRESS_STATE_IN_SESSION</param-name>
<param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
<param-name>org.apache.myfaces.ALLOW_JAVASCRIPT</param-name>
<param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
<param-name>org.apache.myfaces.DETECT_JAVASCRIPT</param-name>
<param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
<param-name>org.apache.myfaces.PRETTY_HTML</param-name>
<param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
<param-name>org.apache.myfaces.AUTO_SCROLL</param-name>
<param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
<param-name>org.apache.myfaces.VALIDATE</param-name>
<param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
<param-name>org.apache.myfaces.ADD_RESOURCE_CLASS</param-name>
<param-value>org.apache.myfaces.renderkit.html.util.DefaultAddResource</param-value></context-param> 
<context-param>
<param-name>org.apache.myfaces.CHECK_EXTENSIONS_FILTER</param-name>
<param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
<param-name>org.apache.myfaces.RESOURCE_VIRTUAL_PATH</param-name>
<param-value>/faces/extensionResource</param-value>
</context-param>
<filter> 
<display-name>Ajax4jsf Filter</display-name>
<filter-name>ajax4jsf</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.ajax4jsf.Filter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>ajax4jsf</filter-name>
<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
<dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
<dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
<dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide your `web.xml` ?

Comment: first part

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

 <context-param>
  <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
  <param-value>server</param-value>
 </context-param>

 <context-param>
  <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.NUMBER_OF_VIEWS_IN_SESSION</param-name>
  <param-value>20</param-value>
 </context-param>

Comment: <context-param><param-name>org.apache.myfaces.SERIALIZE_STATE_IN_SESSION</param-name><param-value>true</param-value></context-param>

<context-param><param-name>org.apache.myfaces.COMPRESS_STATE_IN_SESSION</param-name><param-value>true</param-value></context-param>

<context-param><param-name>org.apache.myfaces.ALLOW_JAVASCRIPT</param-name><param-value>true</param-value></context-param>

<context-param><param-name>org.apache.myfaces.DETECT_JAVASCRIPT</param-name><param-value>false</param-value></context-param>

Comment: <context-param><param-name>org.apache.myfaces.PRETTY_HTML</param-name><param-value>true</param-value></context-param>

<context-param><param-name>org.apache.myfaces.AUTO_SCROLL</param-name><param-value>true</param-value></context-param>

<context-param><param-name>org.apache.myfaces.VALIDATE</param-name><param-value>true</param-value></context-param>

<context-param><param-name>org.apache.myfaces.ADD_RESOURCE_CLASS</param-name>
<param-value>org.apache.myfaces.renderkit.html.util.DefaultAddResource</param-value></context-param>

Comment: <context-param><param-name>org.apache.myfaces.CHECK_EXTENSIONS_FILTER</param-name><param-value>true</param-value></context-param>

<context-param><param-name>org.apache.myfaces.RESOURCE_VIRTUAL_PATH</param-name><param-value>/faces/extensionResource</param-value></context-param>

Comment: <filter>
  <display-name>Ajax4jsf Filter</display-name>
  <filter-name>ajax4jsf</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.ajax4jsf.Filter</filter-class>
 </filter>
 <filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>ajax4jsf</filter-name>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
  <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
  <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
 </filter-mapping>


and others not important
Thank you.

Comment: Are you using facelets? If yes show us first 2-3 lines.

Comment: In the future please edit your message instead of abusing comments to post code in.

Answer (score 4):

We had a clustered environment with IHS directing traffic to two nodes. The deployment did not sync up correctly with one node resulting in the a4J not defined error intermittently. Restarted both the nodes and the server and application started working fine.

Answer (score 1):

> *XYZ is undefined.*

That's a typical Javascript error. As it works fine in the real webbrowsers, all in the server side is absolutely fine.

Only which comes to mind is a conflict in the javascript libraries used/generated. I'd recommend to upgrade to the latest available and align all out.

Answer (score 0):

Add this on every page top.

```
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" prefix="f"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" prefix="h"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://richfaces.org/a4j" prefix="a4j"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://richfaces.org/rich" prefix="rich"%>
```